# How to make HaspMap if we don’t have any haspmap api

Tags: java

**How to make HaspMap if we don’t have any haspmap api?**

Comment: What do you mean? Please be specific? Do you mean mimicking hashmap without using hashmap api?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a class with two properties (key and value) and provide appropriate methods.

Comment: I think `Add Comment`

Comment: Your answer is sufficient?

Comment: "Appropriate methods" means a lot :)

Comment: This is not sufficient to make a `HashMap` !

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a punt, and guessing that you mean `HashMap`, and that the reason you don't have a `HashMap` API is that you are using Java ME.

The answer is to use `HashTable` ... which Java ME does have, AFAIK.

---

On the other hand, if this is a homework question and you have been asked to implement your own hash table from scratch, then you should start by read up on how hash tables work.  Refer to your lecture notes, your Data Structures textbook ... or look up "hash table" on Wikipedia / Google

Comment: My guess is it's a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to design it yourself then you should read a book on datastructures and algorithms at least.

Here's a simple c++ vector based [HashTable implementation.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7c8bf1e747f31f7308ea591cb3bd4129-d8a6f6e6988ed9869ff36c1f09c9e787)

Answer (score 0):

The basis of a hash map is:

1) Having backing storage - an array (or equivalent) that is at least as big as the number of entries you are containing already. Either two arrays one for keys one for values, or an array of tuples of key-value pairs (the latter is probably better)

2) A function that decides which of the key array indices we put new keys into. Usually this will be key.HashCode()%array.Length - but if it is already holding a key and it's not the same key (by key.Equals(), then you try the next bucket to the right, and the next, and so on until we do find one. This is ok to do as long as we do the converse operation when we delete a key from the hash map - in other words, since this 'slide keys over' operation is done because there is no hole, if we make a hole, we must see if a key needs to slide into it to fill the gap (e.g. don't slide any key further left than the first place we would check for it, but otherwise if we can slide left, slide left).

3) Now, to see if a key exists in the HashMap, compute where we would have put it and check that index. If it's occupied and equals(), found it. If it's occupied and doesn't match, check one to the right in the same way. If it's empty, didn't find it.

4) One more operation, a tough one - reconstructing the backing storage with double the size when we're getting close to filling up (the closer to filling up we get, the worse the efficiency is, so you want to double way before you fill up). You have to allocate space for the backing storage twice as big, recompute the position of each key in the old storage for the new one, copy the keys and values over, ditch the old storage and install the new storage.